# Changing String in SQL Table Columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Table with the column date, with each entry being a string in the format YYYY-DD-MM (I know it should be a *Date* data type, but I'm just accessing the data). I would like each entry in the column to be a string in the format YYYYDDMM (without the dashes). Basically stripping the dashes from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute best thing would be to fix the tables and change the datatype to the proper one.

But to answer your question is really just a basic replace.

```
update YourTable
Set YourFauxDateColumn = replace(YourFauxDateColumn, '-', '')
```

Comment: Can you explain "didn't work"? The code posted would remove all occurrences of a hyphen (dashes) in the column.